# How do I access the iframe that does not have an id, name or class

Tags: java, html, selenium, iframe, webdriver

I have the following iframe:

```
<iframe _ngcontent-oyp-c7="" allow="fullscreen" allowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" scrolling="yes" webkitallowfullscreen="" src="https://launch.spribegaming.com/games/launch/aviator?user=164291&amp;token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJQdW50ZXJJZCI6IjE2NDI5MSIsIm5iZiI6MTY0MzcyMjU5NCwiZXhwIjoxNjQzNzQ0MTk0LCJpYXQiOjE2NDM3MjI1OTR9.7st61IJ2K4nOHIhezeg9exDUk-mh0t21e73Dq5QQdbY&amp;lang=EN&amp;currency=ZAR&amp;operator=hollywoodbets&amp;return_url=https://new.hollywoodbets.net" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

How do I get its element as it doesn't have an Id, name or class. As there another way to access it? It a single iframe, so I cannot call it by index like ***switchTo.frame(int  frame number)***

Comment: if it is the only frame in your page, then you can simply call like this: Store the element in a webelement: `<WebElement> String frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe")`

Then you can switch to frame: `switchTo.frame(frame)`

I am am python fellow, so my syntax in java maybe incorrect, but the concept should be same.

In case you have multiple iframes, then you may have to search and find the iframe with unique attribute: Eg: `//iframe[@allow='fullscreen']` or the index of iframe `//iframe[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.switchTo.frame` accepts web-element object argument too.

```
frame_element = driver.find_element(...)
driver.switchTo.frame(frame_element)
```

For locating the iframe in this case I suggest using XPATH.

For a single iframe just

```
//iframe
```

For multiple iframes you have to find some unique attributes filter

```
//iframe[@_ngcontent-oyp-c7]
```

or

```
//iframe[contains(@src, 'spribegaming.com/games')]
```

or even combine conditions with *or/and* xpath operators:

```
//iframe[(@scrolling='yes') or (@allow='fullscreen')]
```